# How to include compiler and linker commands in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I recently installed MinGW to be able to compile in C ++ on Visual Studio Code.
Normal compilation works, but now I would need to run code containing sockets.
To do this, I should include the following compiler and linker commands inserted in Dev-C ++ on VS Code.

*Compiler commands:
-lwsock32*

*Linker commands:
-static-libgcc -std=c99 -lwsock32*

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use the default you need to edit your `tasks.json` to supply additional compiler arguments. The documentation is here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_build-helloworldcpp](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_build-helloworldcpp) if you are using coderunner or some other extension the directions are different.

Comment: IMHO -std=c99 is a compiler flag and -lwsock32 is a linker flag. For a single build command you may use all them merged in one.